# Mathematica file corrupted with the syntax error "Spacer[{0., 0.}], Selectable -> False"

Tags: warning-messages, notebooks

My Mathematica file is corrupted. The error says  `There was a syntax error on line 34457 in the file: xxx.nb. The error was:Spacer[{0., 0.}], Selectable -> False`

I don't really understand the syntax error. I though that maybe there was a space or comma that I could correct...but this line looks identical in syntax to many other lines in the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: This usually happens to me if the file has not been saved properly and parts of it are missing. Assuming you have closed it already and are trying to reopen it now, have a look at [this article](https://support.wolfram.com/12423) for how you can try to recover the contents

Answer (score 1):

My corrupted notebook had this message when I tried to open it

> There was a syntax error in the file being read. Do you want to open
> it as plain text?

As suggested by Lucas Lang in the comment above I went to the [link](https://support.wolfram.com/12423) and followed the instructions. The file was fixed and I am working again.

Hope others find this link and can get their corrupted notebooks fixed. Good luck.